# Small Oscillations and matrices: suggestion about text

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, oscillators, coupled-oscillators, linearized-theory

I'm undergraduate and I'm looking for a text about [Small Oscillations](http://www.google.com/search?q=small+oscillations+matrix) in which matrices are used. Could you suggest me a book or a PDF file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try these books:

1) David Tong: Lectures on Classical Dynamics (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics.htm)

2) V. I. Arnold, Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics

3) L. Landau an E. Lifshitz, Mechanics

Answer (score 2):

The material is standard, so you can probably learn it equally well from many sources, some of which are referenced in the link mentioned in the (edited) question.

Answer (score 0):

The best book, if you want a detailed mathematical analysis (but might be a little dry), is the one by Goldstein. [Here](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~souvik/books/mech/Goldstein.pdf)'s a link to a pdf version of it.